# How can I clear the cache of the Android Facebook app?

Tags: facebook, internal-storage, 1.5-cupcake

My phone (T-Mobile Pulse/Huawei U8220 with Android 1.5) doesn't have much on board space, so I quite often run into the low disk space warning. Looking through the list of apps, I see the facebook app has about 2.5 MB of user data. I suspect most of this is a photo album I looked at recently. But I can't seem to find any option to clear that cache ...

Does anyone know how to? I'm happy to use a file manager and go into the filesystem to delete stuff if I can find it and someone can reassure me that I'm not going to stuff up the facebook app at the same time.

And I don't want to uninstall and reinstall because [nothing will install any more](http://gadgets.stackexchange.com/questions/603/android-an-app-failed-to-download-install-what-do-i-do).

Comment: I've an Android 2.2 FroYo and my facebook app also uses a lot of space. Clearing the cache is disabled for facebook app (and it seems not to be using it). Clearing the data makes me login again and has to sync all my contacts again, its annoying.

Comment: To VC'ers: 12k views is likely not 'too localized'

Answer (score 4):

Here are the instructions for Android 2.2, not sure if it will work for 1.6, but you may want to give this a try.

- Home Screen
- Menu --> Settings
- Applications
- "All"
- Select "Facebook"
- "Clear Cache". If you want to delete ALL data, choose "Clear Data"

These instructions work for all apps, not just facebook.

Comment: I'd tried that, but despite it reporting over 2MB of data, the button to clear data is not present for the facebook app, though I have seen the button available for other apps. It does have a clear cache button, but there is no data in the cache. Thanks for trying to help anyway.

Answer (score 4):

The "clear data" option is available on Froyo (2.2) without rooting your phone. It doesn't show what data is there, however.

Answer (score -1):

The only way you can clear that cache would probably be to delete system files which would only be possible if you were rooted. There might be a market app to help with that, not sure. Try googling something like "android app clear cache". Also keep in mind few apps were written for 1.5.

I would try upgrading to Android 1.6 at least and then see if you have more options. 1.6 is more stable and gives more options too. Plus the upgrade will likely clear out cache and give you a fresh start.

Also if you root your device there would be more opportunities for storing apps and such on sd card which would help with your internal storage issues. Check out XDA Forums to see if rooting your device is possible.

Answer (score -2):

So far I believe the only way to clear your cache is a hard reboot.